Package name change lead to server error - app crashed
In order to follow best practices,
i've changed the packages names accordingly but suddenly received an error on the server

private@Privates-MacBook-Pro Fullstack-project % ls

PROJECT1

private@Privates-MacBook-Pro Fullstack-project % cd PROJECT1

private@Privates-MacBook-Pro PROJECT1 % ls

client          common          node_modules    package.json    server          yarn.lock

private@Privates-MacBook-Pro PROJECT1 % cd common

private@Privates-MacBook-Pro common % ls

index.js        node_modules    package.json    yarn.lock

private@Privates-MacBook-Pro common % cd ..

private@Privates-MacBook-Pro PROJECT1 % cd server
private@Privates-MacBook-Pro server % ls
controllers     index.js        package.json    routers         yarn.lock

private@Privates-MacBook-Pro server % yarn dev

yarn run v1.22.22
$ nodemon index.j
[nodemon] 3.1.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.j index.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@mystartup/common'
Require stack:
- /Users/private/my-app/Fullstack-project/PROJECT1/server/controllers/validateForm.js
- /Users/private/my-app/Fullstack-project/PROJECT1/server/routers/authRouter.js
- /Users/private/my-app/Fullstack-project/PROJECT1/server/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/private/my-app/Fullstack-project/PROJECT1/server/controllers/validateForm.js:1:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/private/my-app/Fullstack-project/PROJECT1/server/controllers/validateForm.js',enter image description here
    '/Users/private/my-app/Fullstack-project/PROJECT1/server/routers/authRouter.js',
    '/Users/private/my-app/Fullstack-project/PROJECT1/server/index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.12.2
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Attaching print screens of my jason ( server and common) + validateForm.js (inside controllers folder / server)
enter image description here
I followed this video from 1:00 to 3:41 min and did exactly that
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xT8jzdn2Pq4
Right after, i was running a yarn dev and got this error ( checked all the names milions of time, all is just like on the video - p.s. there is also a link on the video with all the related files:
https://github.com/lesterfernandez/react-live-messenger/tree/05.share.schema
I was trying to clean cache, "rm -rf node_modules" and reinstall yarn but nothing helped to resolve.
yarn cache clean

yarn cache v1.22.22
success Cleared cache.
✨  Done in 0.08s.
private@Privates-MacBook-Pro server % yarn config list

yarn config v1.22.22
info yarn config
{
  'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com/',
  'strict-ssl': true,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.22.22 npm/? node/v20.12.2 darwin x64',
  lastUpdateCheck: 1713973321143
}
info npm config
{}
✨  Done in 0.03s.
private@Privates-MacBook-Pro server % rm -rf node_modules

private@Privates-MacBook-Pro server % rm package-lock.json
rm: package-lock.json: No such file or directory
private@Privates-MacBook-Pro server % yarn install
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@mystartup%2fcommon: Not found
    at params.callback [as _callback] (/Users/private/.cache/node/corepack/v1/yarn/1.22.22/lib/cli.js:66680:18)
    at self.callback (/Users/private/.cache/node/corepack/v1/yarn/1.22.22/lib/cli.js:141410:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/private/.cache/node/corepack/v1/yarn/1.22.22/lib/cli.js:142382:10)
    at Request.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/private/.cache/node/corepack/v1/yarn/1.22.22/lib/cli.js:142304:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

I need your help to resolve the error. it is my first time when i rename tha package names "@.."

I Resolved it!!! The author had forgotten to mention some steps.
The problem arose when I tried to install dependencies in the server directory, located in the FullStack folder, which contains the following structure:
FullStack (root folder)
---Project (folder)
   --package.json (copy my code below)
   --common (folder)
   --server (folder)
   --client (folder)
---package.json (root file copy this file 

to your folder https://github.com/lesterfernandez/react-live-messenger/blob/05.share.schema/package.json )
The issue was that Yarn was attempting to fetch a package called @mystartup/common from the registry, but it wasn't published. This package was actually a local package that I needed to use across different directories in my project.
After some research and help from Meta AI, I discovered that I needed to update my root package.json file (in the FullStack folder published by the author but not mentioned in the tutorial https://github.com/lesterfernandez/react-live-messenger/blob/05.share.schema/package.json ) to convert it to a private workspace. I added the following lines:
{
"name": "Fullstack-project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"license": "MIT",
"private": true,
"workspaces": [
"packages/*"
]
}

This change allowed me to use local packages across directories. However, I soon realized that I also needed to update the package.json file in the Project folder. The author hadn't published the file, but with Meta AI's assistance, I added the necessary code:
{
"name": "packages",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {},
"workspaces": {
"packages": ["common", "server", "client"]
}
}

This update enabled me to use the local packages in the common, server, and client directories.
After making these changes, I ran yarn install in both the root FullStack folder and the Project folder. Finally, I was able to start the server using yarn dev in the server directory:
private@Privates-MacBook-Pro server % yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.22
$ nodemon index.j
[nodemon] 3.1.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
[nodemon] watching path(s): .
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting node index.j index.js

Server listening on port 4000
I hope this story helps others who may encounter similar issues. Remember, perseverance and the right resources can help you overcome even the toughest obstacles. Happy coding!
